# How to assign a command for a GTK button of Glade?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glade

I designed the interface and a button with Glade ( the a.glade file). I then compose a C language file ( the e.c file) to assign the command to the button, although it does not report an error, the button does not execute the command, am I missing something in my "e.c" file?

In the a.glade file:

```
      <object class="GtkButton" id="buttonn">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">OK</property>
        <property name="related_action"/>
        <property name="width_request">126</property>
        <property name="height_request">51</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
        <property name="halign">center</property>
        <property name="valign">center</property>
        <property name="margin_left">15</property>
        <property name="margin_right">15</property>
        <property name="margin_top">15</property>
        <property name="margin_bottom">15</property>
        <signal name="clicked" handler="on_buttonn_clicked" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
```

In the e.c file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkBuilder *builder; 
  GtkWidget *window;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  builder = gtk_builder_new();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "a.glade", NULL);
  window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "windoww"));
  gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
  g_object_unref(builder);
  gtk_widget_show(window);                
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

and:

```
// called when button is clicked
void on_buttonn_clicked()
{
  char command[50];
  strcpy( command, "touch a.txt" );
  system(command);
}
```

Comment: Your setup looks okay. Are you sure there is not a permissions issue in the directory you are trying to create or `touch` the file in? Try printing a message to `stdout` in the handler - just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

@DavidCollins Hi! Thanks for your help. I tried adding a flag to my compiled code, and it worked. I have added the **`-rdynamic`** flag, the fully compiled code is:

```
gcc -rdynamic -no-pie -Wall -g -o e e.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Thanks for your help.